# JBDC бросает исключение Bad packet type

Tags: java

Пытаюсь подключиться к mysql но бросает исключение

```
URL - jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(PORT=3306)(HOST=localhost))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=admin_admin)))
Подключаемся
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Bad packet type
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:801)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:390)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:202)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:180)
        at com.app.Application.main(Application.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Bad packet type
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:382)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:124)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
        ... 14 more
```

Код программы

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OracleDataSource oracleDataSource;
        {
            try {
                oracleDataSource = new OracleDataSource();
                oracleDataSource.setUser("логин");
                oracleDataSource.setPassword("пароль");
                oracleDataSource.setDriverType("thin");
                oracleDataSource.setDatabaseName("admin_admin");
                oracleDataSource.setServerName("localhost");
                oracleDataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
                System.out.println("URL - "+oracleDataSource.getURL());
                System.out.println("Подключаемся");
                Connection connection = oracleDataSource.getConnection();
                System.out.println("Успешное подключение к бд");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Порт 3306 100% прослушивается mysql

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      31606/mysqld
```

Пробовал вместо localhost писать ip но все равно бросает это же исключение.
Пробовал вместо драйвера thin ставить mysql, но пишет

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:593)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:390)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:279)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:202)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:180)
        at com.app.Application.main(Application.java:20)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

возможно я не так ставлю драйвер?

Comment: Потому что MySQL и Oracle - разные СУБД.

Comment: Т.е мне надо использовать не OracleDataSource а MysqlDataSource

Comment: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил OracleDataSource на MysqlDataSource

Зависимость которую использовал

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```